# How can I find the position of every mutation where the Allele Frequency is greater than X, in regards to a reference such as Hg19?

Tags: genome, ngs, variant-calling, allele-frequency, hgp

I have a Human genome sequenced in a BAM file (along with other files with the indels, snps, cnvs).

I want to find every mutation with regards to the reference Human genome. However the majority of "variants" are noise/read errors. I am therefore required to filter the variants via a minimum threshold based on allele freq (eg. 0,5).

Using a reference (eg Hg19), how can I find the position of every mutation where the allele frequency is greater than the threshold?

PS. I am just starting, so I don't know which are the best (command line?) tools for the job nor how to build a pipeline for this.

Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Hello and welcome to the world of bioinformatics,

BAM files are compressed formats of SAM and you can read more about it [here](https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/SAMv1.pdf).

To answer your question, I presume that your BAM is generated from a Whole Genome library preparation. Calling mutations on a Whole Genome takes a longer time than a Whole Exome since you are looking at every position instead of the exons of your genome.

What you are looking for is a special format of files called [Variant Caller Format (VCF)](https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/VCFv4.3.pdf) generated by Variant Callers tools listed below in comparison studies. There isn't a tool better than another, they all have their advantages and disadvantages. I suggest that you read about them as they also describe their pipeline approaches.

1. [Comparison of three variant callers for human whole genome sequencing](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-36177-7.pdf)
2. [Comparing the performance of selected variant callers using synthetic data and genome segmentation](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/track/pdf/10.1186/s12859-018-2440-7)
3. [Performance assessment of variant calling pipelines using human whole exome sequencing and simulated data](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/track/pdf/10.1186/s12859-019-2928-9)
4. [Systematic comparison of germline variant calling pipelines cross multiple next-generation sequencers](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-45835-3.pdf)
5. [Variant Callers for Next-Generation Sequencing Data: A Comparison Study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3785481/pdf/pone.0075619.pdf)

Once the VCF is generated, you will also have a column named `AF` which corresponds to the allele frequency also computed when using these tools. There are tools that allow you to filter VCF files to extract the needed information with a wished criteria like [SnpSift](http://snpeff.sourceforge.net/SnpSift.html),  [vcftools](https://vcftools.github.io/index.html), [VariantFiltration](https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360037434691-VariantFiltration). So, I suggest reading the above articles as a start.

As for building pipelines, it depends on what language you feel at ease at. However, if I could suggest, [Nextflow](https://www.nextflow.io/) is a good start. You can also use [Snakemake](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) if you like Python. Or maybe simply `bash` ? In any case, there are many pipelines already made to help you through your needs.

(If this helps, don't forget to either accept the answer, vote the answer or both).